# How to tell the browser to display his default error page?

Tags: php, http, browser

In order to include the right file and display an error page if an error occurs, I have the following code (very simplified) :

```
$page = 'examplePage.php';
$page404 = '404.php';

if (file_exists($page))
{
    require($page);
}
else if (file_exists($page404))
{
    require($page404);
}
else
{
    // Tell the browser to display his default page
}

?>
```

To summarize :

- If I have the file, I include it.
- If I don't have the file, i include the error file.
- **What if the error file does not exist too ?**

I would like it to be rendered as **the default error page of the browser**.

I already achieved this with Internet Explorer by sending an empty content with the HTTP error.
The problem is that the other browsers don't act the same, **they all display a blank page**.

Is there any way to tell browsers to display their own error page ? *(not only 404, but all errors : 304, 500 etc)*

Thank you.

**Edit :** I forgot to tell you that I have the complete control on the headers I send and on the content sent in response.

**Edit 2 :** here is some code

```
// possible paths to retrieve the file
$possiblePaths = array(
    $urlPath,
    D_ROOT.$urlPath,
    D_PAGES.$urlPath.'.php',
    D_PAGES.$urlPath.'/index.php',
    $urlPath.'.php'
);

foreach ($possiblePaths as $possiblePath)
    if (file_exists($possiblePath) && !is_dir($possiblePath))
    {
        if (!is_readable($possiblePath))
        {
            Response::setCode(403); // calls the header(403)
            self::$filePath = self::getErrorPage(403);
        }
        else
            self::$filePath = $possiblePath;
        break;
    }

if (self::$filePath === null) // no file found => 404
{
    Response::setCode(404); // call the header(404)
    self::$filePath = self::getErrorPage(404); 
}


public static function _getErrorPage($code)
{
    if (is_readable(D_ERRORS.$code.'.php')) // D_ERRORS is the error directory, it contains files like 404.php, 403.php etc
        return D_ERRORS.$code.'.php';
    else
    {
        /*-------------------------------------------------*/
        /* Here i go if the error file is not found either */
        /*-------------------------------------------------*/

        if ($code >= 400)
            Response::$dieResponse = true; // removes all output, only leaves the http header
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

And here is when I print the content :

```
    <?php
    if (self::$dieResponse)
    {
        self::$headers = array(); // no more headers
        self::$content = ''; // no more response
    }
    http_response_code(self::$code); // HTTP code
    foreach (self::$headers as $key => $value)
        header($key.': '.implode(';', $value)); // sends all headers
    echo self::$content;
    ?>
```

---

**Edit :** here are some screenshots to explain what I want.

This is what i've got in IE :

[image: Internet Explorer]

This is exactly what i want.

Now, in all the other browsers, I've got a **blank page**. *I don't want a blank page.*

I want, for example, Chrome to display this :
[image: Chrome]

Comment: If your error page itself is missing, don't you have bigger problems than what the user's seeing?

Comment: Just a note: the _browser_ has nothing to do with the 404 (or any other) error page. It's all on the _server_. If there is an error condition seen on the server, it will look for the associated error page listed under **ErrorDocument** in .htaccess, then for custom documents (e.g., /404.shtml), and finally, use its own default page. The browser simply displays whatever the server decided to send it.

Comment: ceejayoz : not a problem, in this case, it just means that I don't have a specific file to display for this error.

PhilPerry : true, but wrong. The server rules, but browsers have default error pages. This is also why the 404 page does not look the same in different browsers.

Fred-ii- : i can't use apache directives. He may 404 things that are not 404 (if the file does not exists on my server, it does not mean that there is no file to load).

Comment: Note: Not all pages are standard webbrowser, many are standard server (eg Apache, Nginx, lighttpd, etc)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I didn't know this. If you know a way to trigger these pages, I'm all opened.

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Comment: In this case, I need to trigger the standard server page. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

### Default error pages

Web Browsers shows default error pages if content is blank, eg. create a empty PHP file (error.php) and put this:

```
<?php
   $status = http_response_code();
   switch ($status) {
     case 404:
     case 500:
        exit;//terminate script execution
     break;
     ...
   }
```

In .htaccess put:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

### Custom error pages

1. Using HTTP status

   You can use [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) for GET current HTTP status, .htaccess file content:

   ```
   ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
   ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
   ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
   ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
   ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
   ErrorDocument 503 /error.php
   ```

   Page error.php:

   ```
   <?php
      $status = http_response_code();
      switch ($status) {
        case '400':
         echo 'Custom error 400';
        break;
        case '404':
         echo 'Custom error 404';
        break;
        ...
      }
   ```
2. Using GET param

   ```
   ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?status=400
   ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?status=401
   ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?status=403
   ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?status=404
   ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?status=500
   ErrorDocument 503 /error.php?status=503
   ```

   Page error.php:

   ```
   <?php
      $status = empty($_GET['status']) ? NULL : $_GET['status'];
      switch ($status) {
        case '400':
         echo 'Custom error 400';
        break;
        case '404':
         echo 'Custom error 404';
        break;
        ...
      }
   ```

**Related:** [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869092/1518921)

Comment: I can't, i'm already in the PHP script and I'm using a router to get the files.
Sometimes the page "example.php" will use a script which is in "scripts/example.php", placing ErrorDocuments would not let me handle what is an arror and what is not.

Comment: This does not answer my question though.
I already know how to set a custom ErrorDocument, my question is when the 404.php file itself does not exist.

Comment: Although you have not understood what I proposed, so I'll have a formulate another response.

Comment: I don't want to display a custom page, I want to display the browser's default page.

Comment: Send `header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');` without content (eg. without `echo ...;`). Note: Not all pages are standard browser, many are standard server (eg Apache, Nginx, lighttpd, etc)

Comment: Why the downvote? Explain so I can improve the answer.

Comment: Browsers do not show default error pages if the content is blank (only IE does this). I'm already fine with IE, so it doesn't help.
For the other part (ErrorDocument), I already handle this in PHP. The reason I don't use ErrorDocument in the .htaccess is because not all URLs correspond to a file on the server. To check if a document is found or not, I need to check several things in PHP and on my database. For example if I ask for the page "test.php", it is possible that the file "test.php" doesn't exist on the server, but I still have content (other than an error page) to display.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have it display its default 404 page, before *any* output, do this:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
```

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

So, for your code, you could modify it to:

```
$page = 'examplePage.php';
$page404 = '404.php';

if (file_exists($page))
{
    require($page);
}
else if (file_exists($page404))
{
    require($page404);
}
else
{
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
}

?>
```

Note the following warning that `header` stuff has to be done before *any* other output:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: Actually, I use ob functions so nothing is printed until the end of the script.

I already tried this : only the http header and nothing else, it didn't work.

Comment: I've just doublechecked it.

It only works with IE :/

Comment: Only IE displays its default page. The other browsers don't (I tried Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera).

Answer (score 1):

I asked similar question before a while ago
[Access apache errordocument directive from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856425/access-apache-errordocument-directive-from-php)

Upshot was either redirect the user to a generic 404 page (so the address changes) `Header("Location: $uri_404");`  or curl your own 404 page and echo it, like so:

```
Header('Status: 404 Not Found');

$uri_404 = 'http://'
    . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    . ($_SERVER['HTTP_PORT'] ? (':' . $_SERVER['HTTP_PORT']) : '')
    . '/was-nowhere-to-be-seen';
$curl_req = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($curl_req, CURLOPT_MUTE, true);
$body = curl_exec($curl_req);
print $body;
curl_close($curl_req);
```

Code credit to @RoUS

Comment: Sorry on further reading you are asking for the default 'browser' 404 page. I don't think such a thing exists (except in IE).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

Comment: Better to use `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");` since you don't know what protocol was used